# Detect a given pattern in time series

Tags: python, time-series, trend

How an I detect this type of change in a time series in python?[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g39IY.png)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Y axis is chopped off from your image.

Comment: In lack of any further information, you can do `if y[i-1] < threshold and y[i] > threshold`.

Comment: Y axis is just number of customers. I was looking for a generic way to detect trend change like in the image without including a threshold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.
I will show one of the fastest and simplest way. It is based on using **correlation**.

First of all we need a data(time series) and template(in our case the template is like a signum function):

```
data = np.concatenate([np.random.rand(70),np.random.rand(30)+2])
template = np.concatenate([[-1]*5,[1]*5])
```

Before detection I strongly recommend normalize the data(for example like that):

```
data = (data - data.mean())/data.std()
```

And now all we need is use of correlation function:

```
corr_res = np.correlate(data, template,mode='same')
```

You need to choose the threshold for results(you should define that value based on your template):

```
th = 9
```

You can see the results:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(data)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(corr_res)
plt.plot(np.arange(len(corr_res))[corr_res > th],corr_res[corr_res > th],'ro')
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks! How did you did you decide to take a signum function for your template and a threshold of 9?

Comment: @KimBe I choose the template according to your picture(with step at the end). You can choose another if you want to. The threshold determination is complex problem and everything depends on your tasks. But you should start with your own experiments on data.